# Filtering User-Defined Types

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am attempting to write a function that accepts a list of `Artist`s and a `Genre` string as parameters and outputs all `Artist`s with that genre. I have defined the data type `Artist` as follows:

```
data Artist = Artist Name Genres
  deriving Show
type Name   = String
type Genres = [Genre]
type Genre  = String
```

My code to implement the function is as follows:

```
getFilteredArtists :: [Artist] -> Genre -> [Artist]
getFilteredArtists xs genre = filter (genre) (map getGenres xs)
```

A sample function call is below:

```
artists = [
  Artist "Grimes" ["Electropop", "Dream Pop", "Synthpop"],
  Artist "My Bloody Valentine" ["Shoegaze", "Noise Pop", "Post Punk"],
  Artist "David Bowie" ["Art Rock", "Pop Rock", "Glam Rock", "New Wave"]
  ]

getFilteredArtists artists "Art Rock"
```

Which  should return `[Artist "David Bowie" ["Art Rock", "Pop Rock", "Glam Rock", "New Wave"]`

My function, however, is outputting a type-matching error and I am unsure why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code should work. It would help if you post the type error so people can have a better idea at what's going on. I can see a few issues with your code.

One, you're trying to filter on genre, which is a string, not a bool. You need to use (==) to compare strings.

Second, getGenres isn't defined but assuming it takes an artist, and returns all the genres, mapping it over the artists wouldn't do what your code appears to want it to do. It would just give you the genres without the added context of the artists.

I think what you want to do is filter the artists where the genre is an element of the current artists.

You can also use a data declaration to make automatically make accessor functions for you without having to manually write them.

```
data Artist = Artist {
    getName :: String,
    getGenres :: Genres
} deriving (Show)

type Name   = String
type Genres = [Genre]
type Genre  = String

getFilteredArtists :: [Artist] -> Genre -> [Artist]
getFilteredArtists xs genre = filter (\x -> genre `elem` getGenres x) xs

artists = [
  Artist "Grimes" ["Electropop", "Dream Pop", "Synthpop"],
  Artist "My Bloody Valentine" ["Shoegaze", "Noise Pop", "Post Punk"],
  Artist "David Bowie" ["Art Rock", "Pop Rock", "Glam Rock", "New Wave"]
  ]

main = print $ getFilteredArtists artists "Art Rock"
```

The above code will output:

```
[Artist {getName = "David Bowie", getGenres = ["Art Rock","Pop Rock","Glam Rock","New Wave"]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
genre :: Genre
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter genre :: ???
```

Instead, what you need is a predicate like

```
getFilteredArtists xs genre = filter hasGenre xs where
    hasGenre :: Artist -> Bool
```

How to write `hasGenre`? Well, you already have a `getGenres` function, and the standard library has a

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

function. `` genre `elem` genres == True `` if `genre` is contained in `genres`, `False` otherwise.